# How can I check if IOCP is enabled?

Tags: libuv

I built libuv on windows and I'd like to make sure if IOCP is enabled and using properly.

How can I check it?   Is there any function to check? I tried to look for any preprocessor in VC setting
but coundn't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Libuv is a wrapper around iocp on Windows. What do you mean with _check if it's enabled_?

Comment: I found several preprocess macros in libuv source files, for example, UV_HANDLE_EMULATE_IOCP. so, I doubut whether this is acutally using IOCP enabled on my windows os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows IOCP is always used.  There are a few edge cases where we cannot use it so we "emulate" it.  One such case is when a TCP handle is sent to another process.  There is no way to check that from userland code.